# Determine whether the function $f(x) = e^x \cos (1/x)$ is uniformly continuous on $A = (0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Determine whether the function $f(x) = e^x \cos (1/x)$ is uniformly continuous on $A = (0,1)$.

I see that the function $f(x) = e^x \cos (1/x)$ is uniformly continuous on $A = (0,1)$. Am I correct?

**My answer:** since the function $\cos (1/x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ so it is continuous on any closed interval not containing $0$ say $[a,b]$, $a\neq 0$. Since $e^x$ is continuous for all  $x$ then we can say that $f(x) = e^x \cos (1/x)$ is continuous on any interval $[a,b]$ such that $a\neq 0$. So $f$ is continuous on any subset of $[a,b]$ so it is uniformly continuous using the theorem that: **A continuous function on an interval $[a,b]$ is uniformly continuous** .

Is my solution correct? If not could you please provide me with the correct solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not correct.

Hint. Any uniformly continuous function on $(0,1)$ can be extended to an (uniformly) continuous function on $[0,1]$. See for example [HERE](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-uniform-continuity-theorem).

Comment: So is my answer correct? ....sorry I have edited the title of my question

Comment: The question asked me if the function is uniformly continuous on the given interval ..... so is my answer correct?

Comment: Can $e^x \cos (1/x)$ be extended to a continuous function in $[0,1]$?